# Java List Pair sorting and printing

Tags: java, list

```
import javafx.util.Pair;
List<Pair> mPairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         for(int c =0; c < 3; c++) {
            String one = input.next();
            String two = input.next();

                int oneint  = Integer.parseInt(data1);
                Pair pair = new Pair(oneint,two);
                 mPairs.add(pair);

                 System.out.println(Arrays.asList(mPairs));
}
```

The user inputs a value: for example - "30 apple" and "10 banana". This is stored using List. The last line code outputs it like this: [[30=apple, 10=banana]]

Now what I want to do is to output the data ascending without the first number and without the brackets, like this:

banana

apple

I have tried several different methods without succeeding.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get the most from this site, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please share what your `Pair` class looks like. When asking questions, it's also good to show what you've tried.

Comment: Why do you call `Arrays.asList(mPairs)` when `mPairs` is not an array? Remove `Arrays.asList()` and one set of `[]` brackets will be eliminated from output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure to utilize the generic types of `Pair`. Currently you're using a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), which can have unintuitive behavior at times. To do this, change `Pair` to `Pair<Integer,String>`.

There are many ways to sort and iterate lists. Here's a concise way to do it in Java 8 using [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) along with a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), and then using [`Iterable#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) along with a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

```
List<Pair<Integer,String>> mPairs = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
    String one = input.next();
    String two = input.next();
    mPairs.add(new Pair<>(Integer.valueOf(one), two));
}

mPairs.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getKey));
mPairs.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getValue()));
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/DhMaUT)

An equivalent way to write those last two lines without any Java 8 features would be:

```
Collections.sort(mPairs, new Comparator<Pair<Integer,String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pair<Integer,String> p1, Pair<Integer,String> p2) {
        return p1.getKey().compareTo(p2.getKey());
    }
});
for (Pair<Integer,String> p : mPairs) {
    System.out.println(p.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Or print using Streams, without use of lambdas: `mPairs.stream().map(Pair::getValue).forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: @Andreas The stream could handle the sorting part also using `sorted`. Come to think of it, all of this code could be made into a single stream pipeline.